# Not receiving the correct output

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am new to PowerShell and I am having the following problem.

When typing the following command for asked value of `CanonicalNameOfObject` I am receiving `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection`. I know that this problem is because that property isn't in a format that is understood by PowerSell in its raw format.

Can somebody help me to put this right? In general I want to have all computers in the company for a specific branch (which is only a separated folder).

[image]

Thank you!

Kind regards
Kris

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property * | 
  Select-Object Name,CanonicalNameOfObject,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemVersion,ipv4Address | 
  Export-CSV c:\ADcomputerslist.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: I have now changed the command to -> Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property * | Select-Object Name,@{n=’CanonicalNameOfObject’; e= { ( $_.CanonicalNameOfObject | % { (Get-ADObject $_).Name }) -join “,” }} , OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemVersion,ipv4Address | Export-CSV c:\ADcomputerslist.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8

Comment: But no result...

Comment: Please don't paste code in the comments. If you want the objects from that container, use `-SearchScope` specifying it's DN.

Comment: @KristianMorozov `CanonicalNameOfObject` is not part of the AD Schema. Is this a custom attribute you've introduced in this particular environment? Or are you perhaps looks for the `canonicalName` attribute?

Comment: canonicalName workt just fine, thank you guys!

Answer (score 2):

If you change the Attributes name from "CanonicalNameOfObject" to just "CanonicalName" you will receive the CN in string format.

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property * | Select-Object CanonicalName
```

Answer (score 0):

A "property value collection" is just that, a collection. You get that a lot in AD, every time an attribute takes more than one value (that is to say "most of the time").

Indexing is required even for singular items, eg. `$AdUser.proxyAddresses[0]`; if you can't be certain there is just the one value then you'll need to iterate.

Note that you can check .PropertyNames for presence of the attribute you want - which is not necessarily a given - and that you can also use `$UserObject[$propertyName]` syntax to access it.